# dynamic html watcher

Tags: html

Hi I want to create a program that can read an url and when some conditions are met, it will do something for me, sort of like a bot. How do I read the html of a webpage and how can I tell it to do something for me. Are there some programs out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

I assume you want to write some integration tests.